# How would I pass one function to another function in the first functions parameters?

Tags: javascript

How would I pass the testx function to the change_text function as a parameter?

```
function change_text(to, id, func) {
this.to = to;
this.id = id;
    this.doit = function() {
            this.target = document.getElementById(this.id);
           this.target.innerHTML = this.to;
    }
func;
}
function testx() {
    alert("TESTING");
}

var box = new change_text("HELLO, WORLD", 'theboxtochange', 'testx()');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By just giving its name (without parens or quotes):

```
var box = new change_text("HELLO, WORLD", 'theboxtochange', testx);
```

Functions are first-class objects, and so their names are references to them.

Within `change_text`, you would then call it by using your reference to it (`func`) like any other symbol pointing to a function, so:

```
func();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have improved the code and now I understand that functions are first-class objects so any objects name is also a reference to it. and that name can be passed to other functions in the parameters by just ommiting the parenthesis around the name.

```
function change_text(to, id, func) {
this.to = to;
this.id = id;
this.doit = function() {
        this.target = document.getElementById(this.id);
       this.target.innerHTML = this.to;
}
this.func = func;
}
function testx() {
alert("TESTING");
}

var box = new change_text("HELLO, WORLD", 'theboxtochange', testx());
box.func()
```

The last line of code calls the function that is passed to the first function.

Comment: The last line does indeed call the function you pass in, calling it as a pseudo-method of the `box` instance. You might find this interesting: *[Mythical Methods](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)*

Comment: (FWIW, updates/comments on your own question should usually be edits to the question rather than answers.)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I will remember that and will in the future update the question with any improvements. Thank you for the link, I will read through it thoroughly and try understand the advanced concepts behind it all.

Comment: In your updated code `var box = new change_text("HELLO, WORLD", 'theboxtochange', testx());` you need to remove the brackets from `testx()`. With the brackets you are calling textx and passing its result as a parameter to change_text; without the brackets you are passing a reference to testx.